# How can I define a local variable in a function in PHP?

Tags: php, global, local

I have this code:

```
require_once('../config.php');

function ha(){
    global $user; /* I need this to define local-only access from this function */
    return $user;
}

echo ha();

echo $user; /* Global variable value */
```

So how can I define a local variable in the function that will be accessed through inside function ha()?

So the output  from the `echo ha();` will be the value $user that is stored in file *config.php*, and the last line `echo $user` needs to be empty on echo...when I define $user in function static I get an empty value...so how can I define a static value of variable in PHP that is read from file *config.php* and only access the value in the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function ha(){
    global $user;
    $user2 = 'abc'; // No prefix whatsoever

    echo $user; // Prints global $user
    echo $user2; // Prints local $user2
}
```

> how can I define a static value of variable in PHP that is read from file *config.php* and only access the value in the function?

It's all about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). If you want a variable to be defined in the configuration file and only be readable from within a function, then your current approach is incorrect.

Anything declared in the main scope (such as the configuration file loaded in the main scope) will be accessible from nearly anywhere in the code. If you don't want variables to be accessed otherwise than through `ha()` then they need to be defined within `ha()`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand what you're asking for here, you could do this:

```
class Private {

    private $user = 'value'; // Declare $user as a private variable

    function ha() {

        echo $this->user;

    }

}

$object = new Private();

echo $object->user; // Returns fatal error
$object->ha(); // Echoes 'value'
```

More on visibility is in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about defining a local variable, but that by itself would not solve your problem.
For the sake of those getting here by a search, I'll answer both.

- How to define a local variable in a function:

PHP defines a variable on its first use. There is no keyword for declaring a local scope. All variables inside functions are local by default (even a variable with the same name as another global variable).

'A first use' means assigning a value, not using the variable in return or a condition. If you are not certain that the variable you use on return will be assigned a value (e.g. inside a *config.php* file), then you need to initialize it using a value of desired type. e.g.: `$user = ''`.

- import an external config.php file inside a local scope of a function

You wanted to:

Define a local variable inside a function, accessible only inside that function's scope. This local variable $user is assigned a value from the *config.php* file.
$user must not be visible from outside of that function.

You need to put the `require_once` statement inside that function.

> If the include occurs inside a function within the calling file, then
>   all of the code contained in the called file will behave as though it
>   had been defined inside that function.
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

```
function ha(){
  static $user;
  require_once('../config.php');
  if (!isset($user)) { $user = ''; } // Only needed if you are not sure config.php will define the $user variable
  return $user;
}

echo ha();

echo $user; // Will output nothing
```

Using `static` keyword will let the function keep the value of $user. This is needed, because if you call the function a second time, file *config.php* will not be included again (`require_once()`).

PHP has three variable scopes, global, local, and static. Static is not the same as **local**, but it behaves the same in a sense to where the variable is accessible. Static scope in a function is a PHP specialty, [read about it](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static).

> when I define $user in function static I get an empty value..

You do, because when you used `require_once()` outside of the function, $user variable was defined in global scope. Then you defined **another** $user variable inside the *ha* function by using $user, without declaring it to be global by `global $user`, as you did later.

Answer (score -1):

```
require_once('../config.php');

function ha(){
    $user; /* THIS I NEED TO DEFINE LOCAL ONLY ACCESS FROM THIS FUNCTION */
    return $user;
}

echo ha();

//echo $user; /* (unnecessary) GLOBAL VARIABLE VALUE, same as echoing the result of the function!*/
```

Please see the documentation on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). The second `echo $user` is now unnecessary. Any variable declared in a function not explicitly set to be `$global` will not be global.